# $L^2$ norm for solutions of evolution equations driven by different elliptic operators

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Let $u$ be a solution of the heat equation
$$u_t - \Delta u = 0, \qquad t >0, \ x \in \mathbb T^d$$
and $v$ be a solution of the bi-harmonic heat equation
$$v_t +\Delta^2 v = 0, \qquad t >0, \ x \in \mathbb T^d$$
with the same initial data $f$.
Is it true that, for every fixed time $T >0$,
$$\|v(T,\cdot)\|_{L^2} \le \|u(T,\cdot)\|_{L^2}$$
holds? That is, in some sense, $v$ is "more dissipated"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. I mean, it depends upon the torus you consider. Notice that in the case of the standard one ${\mathbb T}^d={\mathbb R}^d/{\mathbb Z}^d$, the answer is positive. But if you torus is ${\mathbb R}^d/a{\mathbb Z}^d$, then it is positive if $a\le2\pi$ and negative otherwise. The reason is that both semi-groups $H_t$ and $B_t$ are co-diagonal with an orthogonal eigenbasis, but they have eigenvalues $e^{-t\mu}$ and $e^{-t\mu^2}$, where $\mu_0=0<\mu_1,\ldots$ are the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$. To have the required inequality is equivalent to having $\mu^2\ge\mu$ for every eigenvalue, that is $\mu_1\ge1$. Whence the condition on the size of the torus.

More generally, if ${\mathbb T}^d={\mathbb R}^d/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice, the inequality amounts to the fact that every non-zero element of the dual lattice $\Lambda^*$ has norm $\ge\frac1{2\pi}$. Here $\Lambda^*$ is the set of points $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}^d$ such that $\langle \alpha, p\rangle\in{\mathbb Z}$ for every $p\in\Lambda$.

**Edit**. Here are the details. Let me consider a general torus $T={\mathbb R}^d/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice. Both the Laplacian and its square are diagonal in the Fourier basis of exponentials
$$\phi_\alpha(x):=c_\alpha\exp(2i\pi\alpha\cdot x),\qquad \alpha\in\Lambda^*,$$
where the constant $c_\alpha$ normalizes: $\|\phi_\alpha\|_{L^2}=1$.

The corresponding eigenvalues are $4\pi^2|\alpha|^2$, respectively $(4\pi^2|\alpha|^2)^2$. Decomposing an arbitrary data
$$u(0,\cdot)=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda^*}a_\alpha\phi_\alpha,$$
we have
$$u(T,\cdot)=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda^*}e^{4\pi^2|\alpha|^2T}a_\alpha\phi_\alpha,\qquad v(T,\cdot)=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda^*}e^{(4\pi^2|\alpha|^2)^2T}a_\alpha\phi_\alpha.$$
Using the fact that the Fourier basis is $L^2$-orthogonal, we find
$$\|u(T)\|_{L^2}^2=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda^*}e^{8\pi^2|\alpha|^2T}|a_\alpha|^2,\qquad \|v(T)\|_{L^2}^2=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda^*}e^{32(\pi^2|\alpha|^2)^2T}|a_\alpha|^2.$$

The required inequality is equivalent to
$$e^{32(\pi^2|\alpha|^2)^2T}\le e^{8\pi^2|\alpha|^2T}$$
for $T>0$ and every $\alpha$, that is to $2\pi|\alpha|\ge1$ for every non-zero element of $\Lambda^*$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure I follow completely the following part of the argument. Could you expand on the details a bit please?  "Both semi-groups $H_t$ and $B_t$ are co-diagonal with an orthogonal eigenbasis, but they have eigenvalues $e^{-t\mu}$ and $e^{-t\mu^2}$, where $\mu_0=0<\mu_1,\ldots$ are the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$. To have the required inequality is equivalent to having $\mu^2\ge\mu$ for every eigenvalue, that is $\mu_1\ge1$. Whence the condition on the size of the torus"

Comment: Also, does the same reasoning apply if we replace the bi-Laplacian with a general power $(-\Delta)^\kappa$?

Comment: @Jun Yes, since we just have to check whether every eigenvalue satisfies $\mu^\kappa\ge\mu$.

Comment: The answer is clear.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I'm not an expert in semigroup theory though; so some more details/computations would help a lot

Comment: Sorry, the argument is the following. Take an unbounded  self-adjoint operator $A$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and assume that $Ae_n=\mu_n e_n$ for a complete orthonormal set $e_n$. Then $e^{-tA}f=\sum_n e^{-\mu_n t}(f,e_n)e_n$ and $\|e^{-tA} f\|_2^2=\sum_n e^{-2\mu_n t}|(f,e_n)|^2$. In your situation $A=-\Delta$ and $A^2=\Delta^2$ has the same eigenvectors (@Denis Serre used the term "codiagonal") with eigenvlaues $\mu_n^2$.

Comment: @Jun I posted the detailed calculations. Enjoy.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: More generally, I also wonder: what if you have two different elliptic operators $L_1$ and $L_2$ but you don't know that their eigenvalues are one the power of the other. Can some type of information be obtained anyway about the difference of the $L^2$ norms $\|u(T)\|_{L^2} - \|v(T)\|_{L^2}$ of the corresponding solutions of the parabolic problems?

Comment: @Jun This very general case ($L_1$ and $L_2$) is of course an interesting, much more difficult question. Nevertheless, feel free to **accept** my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll ask the more general question in another post